# IntelliJ CodeStyle Java - wrap if statement

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm having trouble configuring the formatter "correctly".

Intellij is formatting like this :

```
if (person.getPhoneNumber().equals(otherPerson.getPhoneNumber()) && person.getAddress()
                                                                         .equals(otherPerson.getAddress())
       && person.getFirstName().equals(person.getFirstName())) {
    ...
}
```

While I would like to format like this :

```
if (person.getPhoneNumber().equals(otherPerson.getPhoneNumber())
       && person.getAddress().equals(otherPerson.getAddress())
       && person.getFirstName().equals(person.getFirstName())) {
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Try changing Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Binary expressions.

Comment: I did but nothing worked.